# CSS Dropdown menu - not fluent under mainmenu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, web

i implemented a dropdown submenu under my mainmenu on my homepage

If you call the main-website and move with the mouse over the "product" menu item, youll see the dropdown.

http://led-werbeanzeige.de/index.html

Why is the menu not fluent, and shows up so many pixels below the original main menu?

Best regards and thanks for your help
Erik.

Answer (score 1):

ad a rule to your css : .menu ul {top : 20px;};
your code isn't working because your rule $header ul applies for ul that contains options(product, service..) and ul that has products (the one that is the drop-down menu)

Comment: I see, header overwrites with 88px.

Comment: Seems like i fixed it. Do you know why i am not able to move over the 2nd and third submenu <li> ?

Comment: You probably have an event handler 'mouseout' registered for PRODUKTE element that hides the dropdown menu. You can check the relatedTarget property of event object that is passed into mouseout handler function, It holds the element to which you switched mouse cursor. You can check it's ID and if it is the id of dropdown menu - don't hide it.